# Cant uninstall fluxgui - package not found

Tags: apt, uninstall, software-uninstall, f.lux

**Update 23/03/2015:** So when I restart the following blinks for a few brief seconds. So it looks like my laptop is not restarting properly and therefore fluxgui cannot be removed?

I get the first one during boot up. I get the rest while it is shutting down.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:** This, disturbingly also doesn't work. It is still running. I can see the dimming and the gui for flux after these commands and all the others below

```
cornelis@Bob:~$ ps -ax | grep flux
 2280 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/fluxgui
 2306 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py
 3010 pts/13   Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/xflux -z 90210 -k 3400 -nofork
 3113 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto flux
cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:kilian/f.lux
[sudo] password for cornelis: 
 PPA for the f.lux indicator applet
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~kilian/+archive/ubuntu/f.lux
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel removing it

cornelis@Bob:~$ ps -ax | grep flux
 2280 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/fluxgui
 2306 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py
 3010 pts/13   Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/xflux -z 90210 -k 3400 -nofork
 3127 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto flux
cornelis@Bob:~$
```

I have fluxgui set up and working on my laptop. The fact that I cant seem to easily remove it has made me want to remove. I cant find it with `synaptic`. Any software that cant easily be removed is a tumour and this one feels like it may soon be cancerous given the negative reviews I've since read.

Below are terminal commands I've tried and what I get

```
cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo apt-get remove fluxgui
[sudo] password for cornelis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fluxgui
cornelis@Bob:~$

cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo dpkg -r fluxgui
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove fluxgui which isn't installed

cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove fluxgui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fluxgui
cornelis@Bob:~$
```

Thought maybe unsetting the latitude and longitude would help. Apparently not:

```
cornelis@Bob:~$ gconftool --all-entries /apps/fluxgui
 longitude = -<Some number the government knows>
 autostart = true
 latitude = <My mom's basement>
cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove fluxgui
[sudo] password for cornelis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fluxgui
cornelis@Bob:~$ gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/fluxgui
cornelis@Bob:~$ gconftool --all-entries /apps/fluxgui
cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove fluxgui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fluxgui
cornelis@Bob:~$
```

It is still running. Any ideas?

Comment: Far fetched idea here, but did you reboot after removing? It might be you have a leftover process loaded in RAM there and the remove script didn't stop it.

Comment: Yes! I have but I do get warning messages of some sort wen I restart. See the updates. I don't usually see these during reboot, at least not on other machines running Ubuntu.

Comment: I also do get an error message of some sort upon boot up! It appears extremely briefly so is difficult to get a picture of

Comment: Are your code snippets in chronological order? Did you remove the flux repo before trying to uninstall the package? If so, try adding it back and uninstalling.

If this doesn't work run `dpkg -l | grep flux` and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your original command `sudo apt-get remove fluxgui` should have removed the app from your system. The message from apt-get `E: Unable to locate package fluxgui` seems to indicate that it has been removed.

You can check by running `ps -ax | grep flux` and see if there are any processes flux related processes running.

You might want to also remove the ppa for flux if this was how you installed it `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:kilian/f.lux`

Comment: Didn't work. See my comments

Comment: Updates in question thanx to Dumitru's comment!